# Finalizando uma variável de objeto java com null - Ele vai ser retirada da memória?

Tags: java, memória, jvm

```
public class TesteMemoria {

    public static void main(String... x){

        ASayboltFurolViscosity objeto;

        for (Double i = 30.0; i < 40.0; i++){

            objeto = new AlgoritmoASTMD2161_v1999_SSF(i, 
                    EnumTemperuraSSF.t122F_50C);

            System.out.println("Viscosidade SSF: " + i 
                    + "\tViscosidade cSt: " 
                    + objeto.toKinematicViscosity() + "\t" + objeto.toString() );

            objeto = null;

        }
    }
}
```

A minha dúvida é se atribuindo um null a variável 'objeto' será retirada da memória com o passar do tempo. E aproveito para perguntar se tem como saber a posição do endereço da memória de 'objeto' dentro da JVM.

Comment: Creio que as respostas são: sim e não.